# 70s/80s combined horizontal and vertical scrolling coin-op shooter game

Tags: identify-this-game

I would love to know the name of a coin-operated game I played in late 70s/early 80s. It was a small space ship game and initially you flew over buildings horizontally firing forwards and dropping bombs, but it transitioned into vertical scrolling. It was extremely hard as you went on.

The game I am looking for is a bit similar to Vanguard, but with a bit more modern graphics; and instead of up and down firing, bombs were continuously thrown sort of forwards from your spacecraft.

Comment: Mind to add the place (country) you payed it in? Game distribution differed around the planet.

Answer (score 5):

Sega's [Space Odyssey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMV3l-jPbS4) from 1981 fits the criteria mentioned. Starts off flying over buildings, Scramble-style bombs, changes to vertical scrolling, looks very difficult due to extreme jankiness.

Comment: just when you thought you knew _all_ early 80's arcade games... good find!